# Expiration Date Reset/Overriden on App Fabric Cache Provider

Tags: caching, memcached, appfabric, azure-appfabric

I am using

Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache for caching

The problem is when I first add an item to the cache it preserves the time out but if I replace the existing item the cahce overrides the timeout to the default value. Here is the code I am using.

```
DataCache cache= new MyDataCahce();
// time out 30 secs
cache.Add("key",10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
var temp = _cache.GetCacheItem("key");
temp.Timeout(); // minutes =  30 seconds which is correct

// Second time replace object at key
cache.Put("key",20)
var temp = _cache.GetCacheItem("key");
temp.Timeout(); // timeout reset to default and equals 10 minutes which is the default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What 
I ended up doing is getting the timeout of the existing item before I add new item to the Cache.

```
 DataCache cache= new MyDataCahce();
    // time out 30 secs at first
    cache.Add("key",10, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
    var temp = _cache.GetCacheItem("key");
    temp.Timeout(); // minutes =  30 seconds which is correct


    // Second time replace object at key may be after 10 seconds
    var temp = _cache.GetCacheItem("key");
if(temp!=null) // it is not expired yet
{
    var timeOut = temp.Timeout();  // less than 30 seconds should be about 20 seconds
    cache.Put("key",20, timeOut )
    var temp = _cache.GetCacheItem("key");
    temp.Timeout(); // timeout less than 30 seconds 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have noted - and as documented - that [`Put`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424971(v=azure.10).aspx) method "Adds or replaces an object in the cache"

So you must therefore use the [overload of `Put`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff424927%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) which allows you to specify the timespan, i.e.:

```
cache.Put("key", 20, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(30000));
```

Comment: I know there is such method with Timeout. My issue is that when I go to there to replace the existing key value the timeout may have elapsed and I don't know what it is by the time I want to replace I can't simply put 30000.

Comment: Ah, that wasn't not clear from your question. I don't quite understand why you would do this, but it sounds like you will have to get the item, determine how much timeout is left, and set it to that.